# Playing H264 FLV videos on AIR App for iOS / Android

Tags: android, ios, air, h.264, flv

I have an AIR App for iOS and Android that plays FLV videos after some process, so i'm using a `video` element with `attachNetStream` and catching his `bitmapData`.

Works fine with FLV videos that uses VP6 video codec, but when i try to play a FLV that uses H264 codec, only the audio plays.

Seems to be that AIR for iOS and Android is incompatible with H264 FLV videos.

Is that a fact, or there is a way to accomplish what i want?

Comment: Please read this answer I previously supplied for another question. Essentially, you should not use FLV using any codec on mobile for various reasons. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902015/actionscript-3-air-video-make-blink-jump/18964375#18964375

Comment: Thanks @JoshJanusch. I use FLV container because I can manage its bytes from my server with a .net application and serve the video from any time of it without preload.

Comment: If you use StageVideo or StageWebView, you're doing that regardless. iOS retrieves bytes of a file at a time for media streaming. If your server doesn't accept the `Range` header and return a specific range of bytes, iOS will simply fail to play your video. FLV video (and the Flash video components) are very poor for mobile in terms of performance and battery.